# How to Navigate from Fragment to Activity onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

I had Seen many Examples But I am not getting the perfect solution.The requirement is on clicking hardware back I had to dismiss the fragment and again to obtain the same activity.

I had override onbackpress in Activity like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //additional code

    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Here when I am navigating to one fragment so its count is 1 and when i pressed back button it directly closes current activity and fragment also and on fragment part by creating button I had placed **getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();** and it works perfectly but I need this in backpress..Inshort I want to go on activity from current fragment where fragment is attached.Will Appreciate this Solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong may be you are thinking in a wrong way.

lets say Activity have 3 fragments

1-  main content
2-  display something after you clicked something which is on first fragment
3-  display something after you clicked something which is on second fragment

So when ever you activity will start there will be a fragment already loaded which is first fragment.

Now if you want to display second fragment you will replace first fragment with second fragment.

When you will press back button second fragment will pop and first fragment will be there.

That is how you can solve your problem.

Comment: So you want to say that the main content too can be taken as fragment isnt it?So in activity there should not be anything right?

Comment: Yes thats what i am saying .